# Window Desktop Form DropDown Bind Issues

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

This is code i have used to bind the Movie DropDown.In datasource i have two data that i have used to bind the dropdown,movie dropdown bind at page load event level but throw error exception like show in Image:-
[image]

```
public void BindMovie(string date)
{
    try
    {
        MovieBAL objAccountBAL = new MovieBAL();
        drpMovie.DataSource = objAccountBAL.GetMovieByDate(date).ToList();
        drpMovie.ValueMember = "Id";
        drpMovie.DisplayMember = "MovieName";             
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ELog.Write(ex, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void BindMovie(string date)
        {
            try
            {
                MovieBAL objAccountBAL = new MovieBAL();
                drpMovie.ValueMember = "Id";
                drpMovie.DisplayMember = "MovieName";             
                drpMovie.DataSource = bjAccountBAL.GetMovieByDate(date).ToList();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ELog.Write(ex, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

- *For solve this issues i have assign datasource in last after assign
  'ValueMember' and 'DisplayMember'*

Comment: Hey Abhay, if this solved your issue, then you should also accept your own solution.